# multiple ajax calls working synchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ajax code which I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"load_search_list.php",
            async:true,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#loadStatus" ).html('laoding 1');
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("#loadStatus").html(msg);
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'load_search_complete_list.php',
                    async:true,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        alert(msg)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $('input#detail').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:laod_details.php,
                data:{id: $(this).val()},
                async:true,
                success: function(res)
                {
                    $('#detail'+$(this).val() ).html(res);
                }       
            });
        });
});
```

I am using 3 ajax calls mentioned below-
1. this call loads first 10 records from the database and displays to the user
2. On success of the first ajax I am using this ajax call to load rest of the details from database.
3. this ajax coll I am using to load the details of the records fetched from the database.

Now when first 10 records are loaded another ajax call is made to load rest of the records, but In the mean while if I try to fetch the details of any of the record displayed on the screen this ajax call is executed only after second ajax call is completed I even tried with the async true but it did not help me.

Comment: `laod_details.php` shouldn't that be `"load_details.php"`? Without an `error` callback you won't be notified if the the server responds with an error code (such as 404 not found in this case)

Comment: A comma is missing after `url : 'load_search_complete_list.php'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I am not sure about it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('input#detail').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"load_details.php",
                data:{id: $(this).val()},
                async:true,
                success: function(res)
                {
                    $('#detail'+$(this).val() ).html(res);
                }       
            });
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"load_search_list.php",
            async:true,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#loadStatus" ).html('laoding 1');
            },
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("#loadStatus").html(msg);
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'load_search_complete_list.php'
                    async:true,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        alert(msg)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
     },100);

});
```

Comment: this is still making the synchronous calls click function ajax call still waits for the load_search_complete_list.php ajax call to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Change `laod_details.php` to `"load_details.php"`.

The request was failing (or more likely you were getting a syntax error since `laod_details` isn't a valid object name) because of the missing quotations and misspelled url name.
Without an `error` callback in your ajax request you won't be notified if the the server responds with an error code (such as 404 not found in this case). Add an `error: function() {...}` option to your request.

Comment: I am facing with the execution sequence of the ajax calls I am not getting error like 404, etc. I will definitely have error block when I move the code to the website